# Android Studio: How to let the app read text view?

Tags: android-studio, text, text-recognition

I followed this tutorial to make a Text Recognition by camera function.

I want to know how can I let the app read the selected text?

like:

selected text -> click "read" button -> speak the selected text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   TextToSpeech t1;
   EditText ed1;
   Button b1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
      b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
               t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
         }
      });

      b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
         }
      });
   }

   public void onPause(){
      if(t1 !=null){
         t1.stop();
         t1.shutdown();
      }
      super.onPause();
   }
}
```

Here is the content of activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:transitionGroup="true">

   <TextView android:text="Text to Speech" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/textview"
      android:textSize="35dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Tutorials point"
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:textColor="#ff7aff24"
      android:textSize="35dp" />

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:src="@drawable/abc"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat" />

   <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
      android:hint="Enter Text"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
      android:textColor="#ff7aff10"
      android:textColorHint="#ffff23d1" />

   <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Text to Speech"
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the content of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>

      </activity>
```